# how can we upload 4GB file using asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Can we upload 4gb file using asp.net 3.5 version?
or can we make a call from javascript to upload file using WCF service?
any solution to upload 4GB using asp.net 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload that file in chunks. Where you divide large files in small chunks. Here is a complete example where you can do this.

http://aspilham.blogspot.in/2011/03/file-uploading-in-chunks-using.html

And this applied to any .net frawework. Here is other configuration changes that you can apply in your application.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/576395/Uploading-large-files-using-ASP-NET-and-IIS

Comment: Hi Jalpesh.... above examples doesnt work for me. becuase the code is at server while i ma having issue of maxrequest length because of .net version used its 2gb only.

Comment: second link talks about iis 6.0 and i have iis 7.5 and there is no facility to override maxrequest length in iss 7.5

Comment: Yes that's why upload that file in chunk and then again create file again when you done are with uploading large files.

Comment: but how to create chunk at client and then post it to server.... is there any code in javascript?

Comment: This is what you you got in first link.